# Sticker peeled off paint from wall

Tags: repair, drywall, paint

I removed some kid stickers on the wall and it peeled off the paint.  Hoping to fix this myself but not sure on the best route to take. Attaching a picture of the damage, what are the exact steps I should follow here?

Based on initial research, I think the steps are:
(1) get spackle and spread over area with putty knife and wait for it to dry
(2) sand with 100? grit
(3) apply layer of paint (given it's just a few spots, is it ok to skip the primer?)

Any detailed guidance would be appreciated, first time at this.  Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing you should use 220 or finer sandpaper, but beyond that I don't know.

Comment: perhaps the first thing to do, is to wash the wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like that is just the top layer of paint. Assuming that is the case - i.e., the drywall underneath is not damaged beyond small scratches - you don't need to use any spackle. In fact, doing so would be a lot of work because you don't have any real holes to fill - you'd be sanding nearly all of it off.

However, you can't just paint over the existing paint. You need to sand it down so that you don't have real edges from the old paint. Primer wouldn't hurt. If you are going to repaint the same (or very similar) color & finish then you may be able to get away with primer just over the damaged & sanded areas, but that might result in an inconsistent topcoat.

The most important thing though is that you should repaint the whole wall. Otherwise, even with a near-match on the color, the difference between old & new will be quite obvious. If you use a close-enough color, you can get away with painting just one wall and not the rest of the room.

Comment: Thanks. What grit do you recommend to use for this particular job?  And to confirm I understood this correctly, I just need to use primer only on the damaged area right?  And if I have the same color, then topcoat only on damaged area is fine otherwise repaint entire wall.

Comment: What grit sandpaper? No clue. I paint rarely enough that I honestly just don't know. Yes, primer on damaged area will probably be OK. But topcoat really should be the whole wall. Even with a near-match, it will just look different between fresh paint and last year's (or older) paint.